# UIPickerView :CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 nan; 200 291]

Tags: ios

I have one question about UIPickerView ,when I write

```
[self.pickView selectRow:[[FCUserInfo teachYears] integerValue]-1  
inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

It crash like this:

> CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 nan; 200 291]

it happens occasionally,I don't know what to do,so thanks ereryone that can give me help!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have this exception coming in, but I can't reproduce it myself